# Adding Mapbox Layer to Plotly Map Positioned Over Data Layer

Tags: plotly, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to understand how to situate a data layer within a stack of vector layers using Plotly's Mapbox functionality. I *think* this is possible with the following approach. Using Mapbox Studio, I've created two map styles: one which represents the base map that all data layers should be placed on top of and another which represents the remaining map layers that should be layered on above the data layers.

[This example](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/#base-tiles-from-the-usgs-radar-overlay-from-environment-canada-no-token-needed) from the Plotly documentation seems to point to the viability of this approach.

Here's demo code that I put together to try and realize the result I'm after. The last *update_layout* statement is not adding the Mapbox layer. Not sure what I'm missing here. Any suggestions? Maybe the Mapbox style spec can't be passed for additional layers?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

us_cities = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/us-cities-top-1k.csv")

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(lat=us_cities["lat"], lon=us_cities["lon"]))
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="mapbox://styles/diehl/cl9gh775w000014n2jwfncok7", mapbox_accesstoken=MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_center_lat=38, mapbox_center_lon=-97, mapbox_zoom=3.25)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox_layers=[
    {
        "sourcetype": "vector",
        "source": ["mapbox://styles/diehl/cl9gha8ta000914qm137qf52q"]
    }
])

fig.show()
```

UPDATE: Took a small step forward in that I got something to render. Replacing the last `fig.update_layout` statement with the following causes additional circles to be rendered instead of the vector tiles which is strange. The vector tiles referred to here correspond to the border for the state of New Mexico. Not complex by any means. Why that vector tile layer is showing up as additional circles I assume is due to the plot being a scatter plot. Any thoughts about how to get around this would be greatly appreciated!

```
fig.update_layout(
  mapbox_layers=[
  {
      "sourcetype": "vector",
      "source": ['https://api.mapbox.com/v4/diehl.3rvgqhks/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt'],
      "sourcelayer": "new_mexico_bnd"
  }  ])
```

For what it is worth, I noticed in the Chrome dev console the following message: "*Geometry exceeds allowed extent, reduce your vector tile buffer size*"

Comment: i don't have much experience with mapbox, but when I pass `mapbox_style="mapbox://styles/diehl/cl9gh775w000014n2jwfncok7"` and `mapbox_accesstoken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}`, the entire plot is blank. Is it possible that some of your mapbox styles aren't publicly available? For what it's worth, when I use one of styles available to all accounts: `mapbox_style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v11"`, then the figure renders and I am able to see the additional circles around New Mexico that you mean.

Comment: @DerekO Great find! I didn't realize that. They should now be public. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging in the documentation, it became clear that my strategy is misguided. The more appropriate approach is to specify the full vector stack for the basemap and then use the `below` functionality to tell Plotly where to slot a particular trace into the basemap. Here's a working example.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

us_cities = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/us-cities-top-1k.csv")
token = <MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN>

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(lat=us_cities["lat"], lon=us_cities["lon"]))
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10", mapbox_accesstoken=token)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_center_lat=38, mapbox_center_lon=-97, mapbox_zoom=3.25)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

# Statement that tells Plotly where to insert the trace into the basemap
fig.update_traces(below="aeroway-polygon", selector=dict(type='scattermapbox'))

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your question in its entirety (because I am only rendering the small New Mexico sample layer on top of what you already have), but according to the [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/mapbox/#layout-mapbox-layers-items-layer-type), the default type of a mapbox layer will be `"circle"`, so if we add the argument `"type": "line"`, then the border of New Mexico renders as follows:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(lat=us_cities["lat"], lon=us_cities["lon"]))

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="mapbox://styles/diehl/cl9gh775w000014n2jwfncok7", mapbox_accesstoken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN})
fig.update_layout(mapbox_center_lat=38, mapbox_center_lon=-97, mapbox_zoom=3.25)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

## update:
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox_layers=[
    {
        "sourcetype": "vector",
        "source": ['https://api.mapbox.com/v4/diehl.3rvgqhks/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt'],
        "sourcelayer": "new_mexico_bnd",
        "type": "line"
    }  
])

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @DerekO. This is indeed progress but we may still fall short from my desired end state. The goal in the end is to render the stylized vector layer on top of the scatter plot that is represented by the Mapbox style mapbox://styles/diehl/cl9gha8ta000914qm137qf52q. I found in PyDesk as an example that you could not specify a JSON style spec for a vector layer. I am hoping Plotly is different since Mapbox GL JS is under the hood.

Comment: I think this is another piece of the puzzle: https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/mapbox/#layout-mapbox-style  "These layers can be defined either explicitly as a Mapbox Style object which can contain multiple layer definitions that load data from any public or private Tile Map Service (TMS or XYZ) or Web Map Service (WMS) or implicitly by using one of the built-in style objects which use WMSes which do not require any access tokens, or by using a default Mapbox style or custom Mapbox style URL."

Comment: Can we not use a GeoJSON or a TopoJSON file to define the boundaries inside the mapbox_layers config?